# ImportError: cannot import name 'wait' from 'os' (C:\Python38\lib\os.py)

Tags: python, operating-system, wait

I'm working on a Python script that scrapes a website based on user input.  For practice, I'm using a sample website from which I am scraping data.  The issue I have is in my use of the wait(10) method.  The code reads as follows:

```
from os import wait
from lxml import html, etree
import requests

def select_PA_city(self):
    pa_city_list = ["Philadelphia", "Pittsburgh", "Harrisburg", "Erie", "Scranton", "Allentown"]
    print("The major cities in Pennsylvania are Philadelphia, Pittsburgh, Harrisburg,"
          "Erie, Scranton, and Allentown.")
    city_found = False
    while not city_found:
        pa_city = input("Select a Pennsylvania city from this list:")
        for city in pa_city_list:
            if pa_city == city:
                print("You selected " + pa_city)
                city_found = True
            else:
                pass
        if city_found:
            print("That city is one of the top 6 listed.")
        else:
            print("That city (" + pa_city + "} is not in the top 6.  Please try again.")
            os.system.wait(10)
    return pa_city
```

Now I'm using PyCharm community as my Python IDE and the first import statement is not being recognized.  I checked the os.py module in my c:\Python38\Lib\ directory, and cannot find the wait method in there.  How do I locate the actual wait() method definition in another Python module, or is there another Python module that contains the wait() method?  If not, what alternate method should I use for initiating a 10-second delay?

Comment: There is no [`os.wait()` function on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait), and it doesn't do what you think it does. What did you hope it would do?

Comment: I think you are looking for `time.sleep()`, instead

Comment: you can use "from time import sleep" then type "sleep(10)" to wait for 10 second

Comment: Thank you Martijn Pieters and AM Z.  I implemented your solution(s), and it works!